# can't referenced function of shared library which made by rust for android app

Tags: android, rust, java-native-interface

I made a shared library using rust for an android app. When the Android app loads the library, make an error as following:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol 
"rust_crypto_util_fixed_time_eq_asm" referenced by "/data/app/com.kt.ktcrypto-4fggQbbTPHo3WulOyE1JIw ==
/lib/arm64/libE2eCryptoLib.so"..
```

When I look the source the function `rust_crypto_util_fixed_time_eq_asm` , I found the `fixed_time_eq_asm` function support only target_arch `x86, x86_64, arm`.

`fixed_time_eq_asm` is in `rust-crypto-working/src/rust-crypto/cryptoutil.rs`.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Use another crate which does support Android or send a PR which adds Android support. But it seems that the first option is a no go because the last update is 3 years old. It's also worth to mention this: _Rust-Crypto has not been thoroughly audited for correctness, so any use where security is important is not recommended at this time._

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation.
I fixed the problem using the information as follows. https://github.com/DaGenix/rust-crypto/pull/384